# How can I access a string from another scene? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a rock paper scissors game and in one scene in the script "Game", the player choice is assigned a string value. In the next scene in the script "Result", I need to compare the player choice and computer choice. The script is able to access the computer choice because it was defined in the same script and I thought I would be able to access the player choice because I made it a public variable but it says that it does not exist in the current context.

'''

```
// Game script

public string playerChoice;

public void Rock()
{
    playerChoice = "Rock";
}
public void Paper()
{
    playerChoice = "Paper";
}
public void Scissors()
{
    playerChoice = "Scissors";
}
public void Shoot()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
}

// Result script

void Start()
{
    string[] computerOptions = new string[3] { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
    int place = Random.Range(1, 4);
    string computerChoice = computerOptions[place];
    if(computerChoice == playerChoice)
    {

    }
}
```

'''
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a manager gameObject with [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html?_ga=2.187956010.341554129.1593113898-1512222664.1593113898).  On that gameObject you can add a **GameController.cs** script that would look something like this:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public playerChoice = null;
    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Then, in your game script, find and set the playerChoice value from the scene

```
// Game Script
public GameObject controller = GameObject.Find("GameController").GetComponent<GameController>();;

// When updating player choice, use
controller.playerChoice = 'rock'; // etc
```

Now, in the result script you can access the controller script as well

```
public GameObject controller = GameObject.Find("GameController").GetComponent<GameController>();

// Your if check
if(computerChoice == controller.playerChoice)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I typed this out here, so some of the syntax may be incorrect, but that's how I would achieve this!